# Saving image from php id URL using webbrowser in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save a image from webbrowser but can't find an answer for it.

Example of the problem is the URL is `hxxp://domain[.]com/image/?img=1234` on webbrowser it shows the image and the source is `<img src='hxxp://domain[.]com/image/?img=1234'>..`

I was unable to save it using the `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile` and `MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData` methods.

In order to download the file, I will need to session cookie also?

How can I do this?

Comment: That is because you are making a new request to download the file, save the one from browser instead.

Comment: how can i save the file directly from the browser programmatically with command instead of using right click save file..

Comment: im sorry to say that but you simply didnt solve my problem. by saying and multiple ways in doing. pls help me with the commands rather than saying.

Comment: I know, for example, that other person mentioned cache, now you need to google how to (re)save image from cache. SO isn't really a code writing site, and you hardly specified anything. Depending on your conditions some ways of doing it would would be considered "good" and others "bad". So yeah, post some code first, say where the error is and then someone will help you resolve it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Any image that you see in the WebBrowser has already been downloaded to your computer. It is normally cached in the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

or whatever other folder is set in Internet Options. You can get your image from that folder.

The following program shows how to copy file `TDAssurance_Col.png` from the `Temporary Internet Files` folder to the `C:\Temp` folder.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        CopyFileFromTemporaryInternetFolder("TDAssurance_Col.png", "C:\Temp")
    End Sub

    Public Sub CopyFileFromTemporaryInternetFolder(filename As String, destinationFolder As String)
        ' Search actual path of filename.
        Dim temporaryInternetFilesFolder As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache), "Content.IE5")
        Dim pattern As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) & "*" & Path.GetExtension(filename)
        Dim pathnames() As String = Directory.GetFiles(temporaryInternetFilesFolder, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        ' If file found, copy it.
        If pathnames.Count > 0 Then
            File.Copy(pathnames(0), Path.Combine(destinationFolder, filename))
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: @Dan C - Updated answer with example.

Comment: thanks RobertBaron. is there anyway to know the filename of the image that was displayed on the "webbrowser" on the URL loaded ?

Comment: @Dan C - You get it from the url of the image. It is the part after the last `/`. It normally looks like a filename but not necessarily. In your example, it is `?img=1234`.

Comment: sad to say that CopyFileFromTemporaryInternetFolder don't work for me.. i examined C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5 and indeed, some pictures are in the temp folders but not those using the hxxp://domain[.]com/image/?img=1234.

Comment: @Dan C - Could it be in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`?

Comment: @Dan C - I meant, the folder above `Content.IE5`.